# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError JasperReport

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Estoy trabajando con **JasperReport** desde su plugin de *IReport*.

Ya he diseñado todo mi formulario desde dicho plugin pero al momento de correr mi aplicación me da la siguiente excepción:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/beanutils/PropertyUtils
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRAbstractBeanDataSource.getBeanProperty(JRAbstractBeanDataSource.java:111)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRAbstractBeanDataSource.getFieldValue(JRAbstractBeanDataSource.java:96)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource.getFieldValue(JRBeanCollectionDataSource.java:100)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.setOldValues(JRFillDataset.java:1331)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.next(JRFillDataset.java:1232)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.next(JRFillDataset.java:1208)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.next(JRBaseFiller.java:1577)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:149)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:932)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:864)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:88)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:653)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:969)
at REPORTE.FacturaReporte.crearPDF(FacturaReporte.java:51)
```

El código que intenta abrir el JasperReport es el siguiente:

```
public void crearPDF(Factura miFactura, Cliente unCliente) throws JRException {
    //Creo mi lista con los parametros a enviar
    Map misParametros = new HashMap();

    misParametros.put("codigoFactura", miFactura.getCodigo());
    misParametros.put("fechaFactura", new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(miFactura.getFecha().getTime()));
    misParametros.put("dniCliente", unCliente.getDni());
    misParametros.put("nombreCliente", unCliente.getMisDatosPersonales().getNombre());
    misParametros.put("apellidoCliente", unCliente.getMisDatosPersonales().getApellido());
    misParametros.put("telefonoCliente", unCliente.getMisDatosPersonales().getTelefono());

    //Creo la variable que contendrá el reporte
    JasperReport miReporte = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObjectFromFile("src/REPORTE/Factura.jasper");

    // Definimos cual sera nuestra fuente de datos
    JRBeanCollectionDataSource datos = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(miFactura.getRenglones());

    //Preparo para mostrar
    JasperPrint miJasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(miReporte, misParametros ,datos);

    JasperViewer miJasperViewer = new JasperViewer(miJasperPrint, false);

    //Le doy un titulo al documento
    miJasperViewer.setTitle("Factura "+ miFactura.getCodigo() +"");

    //Lo hago visible
    miJasperViewer.setVisible(true);
}
```

Como ya habrán notado, el problema se detecta en la siguiente linea:

```
//Preparo para mostrar
    JasperPrint miJasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(miReporte, misParametros ,datos);
```

Sospecho que se está refiriendo a un *problema con algún JAR/Libreria* o algo asi.
**¿Me brindarían alguna ayuda?**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19716969/getting-noclassdeffounderror-when-running-jasperreports-based-application-from-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: x/y/z/NombreClase

significa que el programa usa una clase `x.y.z.NombreClase` que no está en el classpath.

En este caso, es `org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils`

Haciendo una búsqueda de [org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils jar](https://www.google.com/search?q=org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils+jar) nos lleva a [Apache Commons BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/).

Ahora se trata de averiguar qué versión necesita el `JasperReport` (dependerá de la versión que uses; en la documentación o en el repositorio de Maven te listará las dependencias), descargar el jar e incluirlo en el classpath a la hora de ejecutar el programa.

Aunque al principio puede parecer complicado, usar un gestor de dependencias como Maven o Ivy te soluciona estos problemas de forma transparente.