# Problemas al crear reporte JasperReport con Java 8

Tags: java, ireport

Estoy intentando crear un reporte mediante **Java** con **JasperReports**, he intentado muchas opciones y no he podido realizarlo, soy nuevo en el tema, lo que deseo hacer es llenar un reporte con parámetros desde java, osea es una receta medica en la que el reporte llevará texto contenido en un `Textfield` y de un `TextArea` pasados como parámetros desde java al Reporte Jasper, cosa que no puedo hacer ni siquiera que se abra el reporte ya que me lanza error, cabe mencionar que los datos vienen de los campos de texto y no de base de datos.

Espero puedan apoyarme por favor, dejo el código que utilizo y el error que me da.

```
private void BTImprimirActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           

    try{

  HashMap parametro = new HashMap();
  parametro.put("paciente",TFPaciente.getText());
  parametro.put("indicaciones", TAConsulta.getText());

  JasperReport reporte = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("C:\\Users\\Saul\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\GinecologiaHEG\\src\\ginecologiaheg\\receta.jrxml");    

  JasperPrint jasperPrint  = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reporte,parametro);
  JasperViewer view =  new JasperViewer(jasperPrint,false);
  view.setVisible(true);
} catch(Exception ex){
    System.out.println("Error: "+ex);
}


}
```

Error:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/springframework/beans/factory/support/BeanDefinitionRegistry  at
>   java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRClassLoader.loadClassForRealName(JRClassLoader.java:156)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRClassLoader.loadClassForName(JRClassLoader.java:114)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.ClassUtils.instantiateClass(ClassUtils.java:59)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistry.instantiateRegistry(DefaultExtensionsRegistry.java:294)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistry.loadRegistries(DefaultExtensionsRegistry.java:270)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistry.loadRegistries(DefaultExtensionsRegistry.java:190)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistry.getRegistries(DefaultExtensionsRegistry.java:153)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistry.getExtensions(DefaultExtensionsRegistry.java:125)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.DefaultJasperReportsContext.getExtensions(DefaultJasperReportsContext.java:277)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.component.ComponentsEnvironment.findBundles(ComponentsEnvironment.java:109)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.component.ComponentsEnvironment.getCachedBundles(ComponentsEnvironment.java:99)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.component.ComponentsEnvironment.getBundles(ComponentsEnvironment.java:87)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRReportSaxParserFactory.getSchemaLocations(JRReportSaxParserFactory.java:103)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.BaseSaxParserFactory.configureParser(BaseSaxParserFactory.java:163)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.BaseSaxParserFactory.createParser(BaseSaxParserFactory.java:118)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlDigesterFactory.createParser(JRXmlDigesterFactory.java:1597)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlDigesterFactory.createDigester(JRXmlDigesterFactory.java:1566)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:263)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:219)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:194)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:185)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compile(JasperCompileManager.java:288)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReport(JasperCompileManager.java:575)
>     at
>   ginecologiaheg.consulta.BTImprimirActionPerformed(consulta.java:213)
>     at ginecologiaheg.consulta.access$300(consulta.java:29)     at
>   ginecologiaheg.consulta$4.actionPerformed(consulta.java:131)  at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
>     at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
>     at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
>     at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
>     at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
>     at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)    at
>   java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)  at
>   java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)  at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)     at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)     at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
>     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
>     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
>     at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)    at
>   java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)   at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
>     at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)   at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionRegistry  at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     ... 64 more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al parecer hay algún error en las librerías de jasper. Justo en el error no se ve el "Caused by..." , no puedo pedirte que agregues el caused by en comentarios porque no tengo la reputación necesaria, pero te dejo algunas web que hablan de este tema, con errores similares, quizá te ayude a encontrar alguna solución:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25988216/exception-in-java-with-ireport-5-5-1][1]

[java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError JasperReport](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/172434/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-jasperreport][1])

Espero ser de ayuda, al menos te va a dar una idea general, yo use JasperReport y obtenés resultados muy buenos, pero es complicado hasta que se da con las librerías correctas.

Saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias por la información, revise y realice lo que se indica, agregando al Classpath las librerias pero aun sigue marcando el mismo error.